# watchdog (Python's library) - How to send signal when a file is modified?

Tags: python, pyqt, watchdog, python-watchdog

My code for a class that detects when a specific file has been modified:

```
class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler, QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(MyEventHandler, self).__init__()
        self.filename = filename

    def on_modified(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory and event.src_path.endswith(self.filename):
            print "modified"
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("fileModified"))


class WatchOutForFileModifications(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, path, filename):
        super(WatchOutForFileModifications, self).__init__()
        self.path = path
        self.filename = filename
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = MyEventHandler(self.filename)
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.path, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.connect(self.event_handler, QtCore.SIGNAL("fileModified"), self.modified)


    def modified(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("fileModified1"))
```

And the code snippet for the application itself:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)

        path = "somePath"
        filename = "someName"

        self.fileWatcher = WatchOutForFileModifications(path, filename)
        self.fileWatcher.start()
        self.connect(self.fileWatcher, QtCore.SIGNAL("fileModified1"), self.fileModified)
        self.show()

    def fileModified(self):
        print 1
```

Problem is that when a file is modified, I get a non-stop stream of 1 being printed. I realise that there shouldn't be signal being emitted/connected that way in the `WatchOutForFileModifications` class, but I don't understand how is the API: http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.observers.api.EventEmitter -- supposed to work. At least I assume that this is the API I should be using to listen to file modifications.

**EDIT**

Working code after some modifications:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic

from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer

class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler, QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(MyEventHandler, self).__init__()
        self.filename = filename
        self.signalName = str(filename) + "_modified"

    def on_modified(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory and event.src_path.endswith(self.filename):
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL(self.signalName))


class FileModificationWatcher(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, path, filename):
        super(FileModificationWatcher, self).__init__()
        self.path = path
        self.filename = filename
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = MyEventHandler(self.filename)
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.path, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()

    def run(self):
        pass

    def getEmitter(self):
        return self.event_handler

    def getSignalName(self):
        return self.event_handler.signalName

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)

        path = "somePath"
        filename = "someName"

        self.fileWatcher = FileModificationWatcher(path, filename)
        self.fileWatcher.start()
        self.connect(self.fileWatcher.getEmitter(), QtCore.SIGNAL(self.fileWatcher.getSignalName()), self.fileModified)
        self.show()

    def fileModified(self):
        print 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `WatchOutForFileModifications` you're repeatedly connecting the signal to the slot in the run function. To fix the problem you're having, take the `self.connect` call and move it into the `__init__` of the class, like so:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer


class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler, QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(MyEventHandler, self).__init__()
        self.filename = filename

    def on_modified(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory and event.src_path.endswith(self.filename):
            print("modified")
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("fileModified"))


class WatchOutForFileModifications(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, path, filename):
        super(WatchOutForFileModifications, self).__init__()
        self.path = path
        self.filename = filename
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = MyEventHandler(self.filename)
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.path, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
        self.connect(self.event_handler, QtCore.SIGNAL("fileModified"), self.modified)

    def run(self):
        pass

    def modified(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("fileModified1"))


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        path = r'D:\Code\\'
        filename = "Hexagon_Grid_Creation.py"

        self.fileWatcher = WatchOutForFileModifications(path, filename)
        #self.fileWatcher.start()
        self.connect(self.fileWatcher, QtCore.SIGNAL("fileModified1"), self.fileModified)
        self.show()

    def fileModified(self):
        print(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

In this case, you probably don't need the `QThread`; the file is being monitored by the event handler so you don't really have anything else that you need to run in the background. I think you could do away with that class altogether and just instantiate the event handler in the `MainWindow` class.

Comment: I actually realised that I can make the connection straight from the `MyEventHandler` to the `MainWindow`, skipping the signal handling in `WatchOutForFileModifications` altogether.

Answer (score -1):

In your WatchOutForFileModifications class, try connecting the signal in the **init** method.